# How to create models dynamically

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to PHP. I want to know how to create Model part in CakePHP without writing manually. Dynamically create model for database table name? Is there any datasource available for that?

Comment: "I am new to PHP" --- so start from php basics, not from frameworks. New in engineering never build planes.

Comment: So is this CakePHP or Codeigniter?

Comment: Wanting to dynamically create models is the wrong approach. Do you mean you want to ***bake*** a model file? Then please read the manual.

Comment: What is the exact reason why you want to have dynamic models? If you explain that we might to be able to help you in a better way. Do you have many many models or is it just you don't want to write them by hand?

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 1.2 created model classes automatically if it can't find the defining source file and there is a database table with a name that matches. This lead to surprising behaviour if for some reason the source file does not have the correct name, e.g you add a method or a relation and it's not found. I don't know if this feature is still available in 1.3 and 2.0.

To use an automatically generated model you could use either the `$uses` Controller attribute:

```
public $uses = array('Product', 'Post', 'Comment');
```

or use the `loadModel` method.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 2 you could manually instantiate the `Model` class:

```
$Post = new Model(array('table' => 'posts', 'name' => 'Post', 'ds' => 'connection2'));
```

See also http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Model__construct